# "Ірої-комічна" поема. Що таке "ірої"?

Tags: вживання-слів, невідоме-слово

З книги "Поетика Тараса Шевченка" Бовсунівської Тетяни:

> Жанрова група поезій світової традиції віршування у Т. Шевченка має виразне рецептивне забарвлення, яке він зовсім не намагається приховати. Насамперед серед жанрів цієї групи треба назвати поему: ліро-епічну (“Катерина”), епічну (“Гайдамаки”), **ірої-комічну** (“Сон”) та сатиричну (“Кавказ”).

Що таке "ірої"? Знаходжу всюди лише у поєднанні зі словом "комічна". Окремого пояснення слова ніде не бачу. Де таке шукати взагалі?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово "[ірої-комічна](http://litmisto.org.ua/?cat=63&paged=32)" походить від давньогрецького iritos - героїчний та komikos — комічний. Цей жанр вперше виникнув у Стародавній Греції ("Батрахоміомахія" (“Війна мишей та жаб”), а тому у нашій мові залишилася назва цього жанру, хоч і трохи змінена (так само як і "іронія", "драма", тощо). Не дивно, що ви більше ніде не можете знайти окреме слово "ірої" (воно не українське, і ніде окрім драматургії не вживається).

Comment: Додам, що іноді пишуть «іроїкомічна» (без дефіса).